# Delta<T> As a odata parameter in web api Action

Tags: odata, webapi, delta

I have requirement where i want to take two parameters for an action in odata, First parameter as string and second as delta, where T is entity type. There isn’t any syntax error but whenever i m making a post request it is throwing an exception stating this property is not in the delta, though i am passing the valid property from request body.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar requirement and I found when using Delta in Action, you need to define the return type which is the generic type T in Delta. Although the controller returns NoContent, the odata framework still need a return type.